# Casting object array with unknown value types to a double

Tags: object, types, casting, double

I am writing a quartile function and I am stuck with this problem. I am pulling a array with unknown types and length, but i need to cast it to a double.

This is my current code which compiles but throws an invalid cast exception:

double[] array1 = array.Cast().ToArray();

any help would be greately appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Some types simply cannot be converted to `double`. For example, what's supposed to happen with an array of `System.Drawing.Rectangle` or an array of `System.Windows.Controls.Button`? Please explain this in your question, so we can point you into the right direction.

Comment: I only want the double values in the array, So if I iterate through the array. and just get all the doubles into a list.and after I have the list I can then convert the list to a double array. Is this possible? I can think that i might have to do a foreach loop? can you please give me an idea of how this code will look like creating the list looping through the object array to get all the doubles and putting it into a double array.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that should be:

```
double[] array1 = array.OfType<double>().ToArray();
```

You will need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file for this to compile.

Comment: this is what i currently have:

Comment: I still get errors, is there anyway this could work:List <double> doubleobjects = new List <double>();
      foreach (double obj in array)
      {
        try
        {
          doubleobjects.Add(obj);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          //messageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
      }
      double[] array2 = array.Cast<double>().ToArray();

Comment: @user1441726 No, this cannot possibly work if `array` contains items that cannot be converted or cast into `double` values. From your above comment (on the question), I figured you only want to extract those items that are `double` values, which is what my code snippet does.